# How to generate the correct dist files?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I have Vue project that is not initialed by vue-cli. now I found the

```
npm run build
```

the output is not the correct format, it is disorder files there.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

How can I get the better dist files? such as the `vue-cli` run build gets the correct dist files? you see, mine there is no `index.html` even.

Is it necessary to convert the project to vue-cli initialed project, if is, then how?

My project directories is bellow：

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In webpack config you have probably output > filename: '[name][hash].js' (or similar) so your file names look so wierd. Your JS and CSS files in dist folder have already hardcoded this names.

If you want you file names without "hash" just change webpack config to output > filename: '[name].js'